# Clone of Google Data Studio Select with option “only”

Tags: user-interface, vue.js, vuetify.js

Do you know where can i find an implementation of the super select of Google Data studio with the "Only" to select only that element ?

[image: dataStudio]

you can also filter results , super handy if the list is long :

[image: filter]

Comment: This feature have not been implemented yet. You can try to ask it on Vuetify github. Anyways, if you give an empty array as v-model to your v-select, your user will be able to select an only option.

Comment: This isn't a google-data-studio question at all, slightly confusing tagging.

Comment: Good question, I see your vote is `-1` and I `upvote` it . I don't know why your good question has `-1` score?!!

Comment: @AmerllicA Because it's off-topic. It isn't about programming. Probably belongs on [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com).

Comment: Question is a bit unclear, however OP put `vuetify` tag so I presumed he wanted vuetify implementation of this behavior. Perhaps he will clarify, and edit the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<strike>There is a [feature request](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/pull/4179) for `select-all` functionality, and apparently it will be possible using to-be-implemented `scoped-slot` called `prepend-item`.

So currently you will need some workaround.</strike>

Updated codepen with `prepend-item` slot which came in version 1.2:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EdVpmY
<sub>(must look into filtering more so I'll update if something changes)</sub>

Note `prepend-item` is also part of the parent `v-list` component, so we can't easily fix controls to the top.

```
<template slot="prepend-item">
  <v-list-tile @click.stop="selected = selectedAll ? [] : states.slice()">
    <v-list-tile-action>
      <v-icon :color="selected.length > 0 ? 'indigo darken-4' : ''">{{ icon }}</v-icon>
    </v-list-tile-action>
    <v-list-tile-title>Select All</v-list-tile-title>
  </v-list-tile>
  <v-divider class="mt-2"></v-divider>
  <v-list-tile class="search-tile">
    <v-text-field v-model="q" prepend-inner-icon="search" class="pt-0"></v-text-field>
  </v-list-tile>
</template>
```

---

With regards to `select-only` functionality, you can use already supported [`scoped-slot`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html#Scoped-Slots) `item` (see `scoped slots` in [API docs](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/selects#api)) , and add `select-only` button yourself:

```
<v-select v-model="selected"
          multiple
>           
    <template slot="item" slot-scope="data">
        <v-list-tile-content>
            <v-list-tile-title>
                {{ data.item }}
            </v-list-tile-title>
        </v-list-tile-content> 

        <v-list-tile-action class="hidden">
            <v-btn @click.stop="selected = [data.item]">ONLY</v-btn>
        </v-list-tile-action>
    </template>
</v-select>
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xzzeZg), note that some CSS is added as well.

[Expanded codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MXXRMp) with `select-all` workaround using `watch`, and one of the items is `"All"`. So if we want array of selected without `"All"` we can do something like `return this.selected.filter(v => v !== "All")` in computed property or wherever it's needed.

Comment: wow thank you ! I have edited my question with a new screenshot about filtering the results, super handy when the list is long. If you have clue how to do that with vuetify :) :) best regards

Comment: @LaurentDebricon Currently, you can just add `autocomplete` property to v-select and it works. But note it will not have the layout that you want. I presume what you aim to achieve will be possible with upcoming `prepend-item` slot I had mentioned. So just wait for vuetify version update if possible. Perhaps I can come back to this when new vuetify version which includes that slot arrives, but I'm not sure what's ETA.

Answer (score 1):

As much as I can see this is a custom component. The one you are showing is probable made with angular + material like in this example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-select-multi-c6vtux

So I think that you probably will end needing a component like vue-multiselect, that is fully featured and probably will accomplish what you need and more, the only thing is that you will need to work on it to use material styles.
https://github.com/shentao/vue-multiselect
https://vue-multiselect.js.org

I guess, that if you need more features, you might be able to customize the template https://vue-multiselect.js.org/#sub-custom-option-template

Now check ¨Custom configuration¨, there you will find some examples that will show you you can actually do something like the "only" with some effort.

This is the most complete component I have found for vuejs to handle multi select.

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

It's a feature that hasn't been implemented. Ask you desire feature [HERE](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues).

Hope it help you.